# Working with ctrl+c in vscmdshell

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, cmd

I downloaded vscmdshell from the codeplex site. I was very much impressed with this tool . However I cannot break the current operation using ctrl+C in vscmdshell .

I have downloaded the source code form the codeplex site , but I am not able to solve this issue .

Can someone care to help , please

Thanks and Regards
Gagan Janjua